# Assigning an enum a max value via numeric_limits?

Tags: c++, enums, limits

I'm having trouble assigning an element in an `enum`a max value. First:

```
protected:
    enum {DEFAULT_PADDING=std::numeric_limits<enum>::max()};
```

Results in:

```
./basecode.h:30:51: error: expected identifier or '{'
    enum {DEFAULT_PADDING=std::numeric_limits<enum>::max()};
                                                  ^
./basecode.h:30:59: error: expected a type
    enum {DEFAULT_PADDING=std::numeric_limits<enum>::max()};

(and a couple of others)
```

Second, switching to:

```
protected:
    enum {DEFAULT_PADDING=std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()};
```

Results in:

```
./basecode.h:30:27: error: expression is not an integral constant expression
    enum {DEFAULT_PADDING=std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()};
```

How do I have `numeric_limits` give me a value that I can use at compile time for an `enum`?

---

The library is older, so it supports a lot of older compilers and IDEs. I need something that is at least C++03 and preferably C++98.

And standard caveats apply: this is a simple make based project. It does not use Autotools, it does not use Cmake, it does not use Boost, etc.

Comment: Are you compiling with `-std=c++11`?

Comment: `numeric_limits::max` is declared as `static` whereas enums require constants.

Comment: @Jonathan - I'd be surprised if it was not constant. Are you saying it can somehow change at runtime?

Comment: @Barry - I added additional information. In short, I *need* C++03 and C++11. I *want* C++98, too.

Comment: @jww I mean the error message makes it pretty clear, **expression is not an integral constant expression**.

Comment: @JonathanPotter - OK, thanks. My apologies, but it does not make sense to me. `max()` does not change after compiling or at runtime, so its not clear why I can't use it. (And I just performed a `cat /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/limits | grep "static const"` and it showed up everywhere. 374 times to be exact, according to `wc -l`).

Comment: Have a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr - `constexpr` was added to the language to make it possible for functions to be evaluated at compile time. Simply marking a function as returning a `const <something>` isn't enough to make it a compile-time constant - if it was, `constexpr` would be redundant. The compiler **might** optimise `max()` into a constant (and probably will) but that's not enough to satisfy the requirements of `enum`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++03, [`std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max) was simply `static`. In C++11, it became `static constexpr`. You need the latter in order to be used in an integral constant expression, so simply compiling with `-std=c++11` will do.

If you can't use C++11, you can just use [`UINT_MAX`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits).

Comment: Note that in VC++ 2013 it's still just `static`, so is compiler dependent.

Comment: This library is old, and it supports a lot of old compilers and IDEs. I need C++98, C++03 and C++11. Is `numeric_limits` the wrong tool for the job? (I thought that was supposed to be used in C++).

Comment: `enum` is fine. As is `numeric_limits`. You just can't combine the two before C++11.

Comment: `numeric_limits` won't be evaluated at compile time except in C++11, so you probably should just use `UINT_MAX`.

Comment: To finish out *How do I have `numeric_limits` give me a value that I can use at compile time for an enum?*, the answer is ***I can't***. Sorry about asking a question that did not have an answer...

Comment: `UINT_MAX` can also be spelled `-1U`, for those of us with an aversion to macros.